# fancybox3, how to make rounded corners on slideshow images

Tags: slideshow, fancybox-3

I can produce a rounded frame with css but still a square image in rounded frame. Does anyone have a better solution please.

Comment: What did you try? Content wrapping element has different class name based on content type, you can use that.

Comment: Hi Janis - I use the following code:
.fancybox-content,
.fancybox-image-wrap {
  background: #000 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  border:10px solid black !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px !important;
-ms-border-radius: 20px !important;
-o-border-radius: 20px !important;
border-radius: 20px !important;
}

I quite like the effect but wonder if I can do something direct to the image.

Comment: Sorry @Janis tried to remember how to format these comments and failed. 5mins to edit comment seems silly to me.
     .fancybox-content, .fancybox-image-wrap { 
      background: #000 !important; 
      box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) !important; 
      overflow: visible !important; 
      border:10px solid black !important; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px !important; 
      -ms-border-radius: 20px !important; 
      -moz-border-radius: 20px !important; 
      border-radius: 20px !important; }